# Service starting after some time in BootCompleteReceiver?

Tags: android, service

I am creating an android application. It whitelist all the numbers added to the application! Using services when a call is made that is not in whitelist will be disconnected!

Everything works perfect! I added BootCompleteReceiver to start the service when phone is booted! But i faces an issue that, When user reboot the system, it takes some time to start the service! So, in that specific time user can make any calls!

How could i handle this issue! Please suggest a method!

Code:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CallService.class));
                    //Util.scheduleJob(context);
                } else {
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, CallService.class));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there could be many apps which would be registering for this Broadcast, there could be slight delay on receiving the Intent in your app. The speed however depends on several factors like the CPU speed of the device, the capacity of system RAM on the device etc.

Since the behavior is out of your control, best you can do is to set priority for the receiver in you AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"/>
```